# Multiplying several variables in python

Tags: python, variables

My code is as follows:

```
box = raw_input('What is your box size')

op1 = float(box)*602,216,900,000,000,000,000,000

op2 = op1 * 1,000

print op2
```

How do a recieve the value of op1 times 1,000 instead of having it repeated 1,000 times? When I use the float() argument I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Comment: Python does **not** use the comma as a thousands separator. The comma makes your items **tuples**.

Comment: Not that your code here actually produces the exception you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
op2 = op1 * 1000
```

commas are not allowed in valid `int` declarations.

Applying this to your entire question:

```
box = raw_input('What is your box size')

op1 = float(box) * 602216900000000000000000

op2 = op1 * 1000

print op2
```

Your code should work fine now.  Here's a little more background on how declaring number's in python [works](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_numbers.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The error you posted indicates that you've somehow got a bad value in your `box` variable from user input, but the actual problem in your code is that you're creating [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple), not large numbers.

You're attempting to use "`,`" as a thousands separator. This is *not allowed* in numeric literals in Python. Instead, what the parser will see is a *tuple*:

```
op1 = (float(box)*602, 216, 900, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

If you then want to multiply the result by 1000, you must still omit the commas:

```
op1 = float(box) * 602216900000000000000000
op2 = op1 * 1000
```

...or you'll just end up with the result above, inside a tuple with a `0` as the second element.

---

This second problem is the same, although it's trickier to look at if you're not familiar with how tuples and precedence work in Python.

Let's say we've fixed the first line, so that `op1` is indeed a float (let's say `2.0`) instead of a tuple. Then the interpreter encounters this line:

```
op2 = 2.0 * 1,000
```

This is equivalent to:

```
op2 = 2.0*1, 0  # We will assign a two-element tuple to the name "op2".
```

Which results in:

```
op2 = (2.0, 0)  # The first element is now 2.0*1, and the second element is 0.
```

---

Once you've fixed the syntax problems, you might want to represent that nasty literal up there in a more recognizable form, to clean up your code:

```
op1 = float(box) * 6.022169 * 10**23
```

...or even better, put it in a variable so you can use it elsewhere and know what the heck is going on:

```
not_quite_avogadro_const = 6.022169 * 10**23
op1 = float(box) * not_quite_avogadro_const
```